# Initialize variable as float

Tags: php

Never had to do such a basic thing before. How do I initialize a variable as a float before doing logic? Do either of these examples make sense?

```
$var = 0.0;

$var = (float) 0;
```

Comment: PHP is loosely-typed, especially with numbers. Why does it matter if it's `int(0)` or `float(0)`?

Comment: @myol - Unclear what your asking, here. If you want to initialize a float, yes, you can do it this way. Probably best practice to use: `$var = (float) 0.0`

Comment: This sort of question implies that you are attempting to solve the wrong problem. If $var needs to be a float, PHP will convert it to a float without requiring you to do anything. Therefore, you need to explain the real problem to get a worthwhile solution.

Comment: Clarity for future coders really

Comment: Even when you have `declare(strict_types=1);`, it allows `float` and `int` interchangably.

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both make sense, the first is shorter, with the second you can initialized with a dynamic value, your choice !

EDIT : But I agree with @Niet the Dark Absol, it poorly matters since you use test function such as [ctype_digit](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ctype-digit.php), or [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-numeric.php).

Answer (score 2):

from http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

> Floating point numbers (also known as "floats", "doubles", or "real
>   numbers") can be specified using any of the following syntaxes:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $a = 1.234; 
> $b = 1.2e3; 
> $c = 7E-10;
> ?>
> ```

so defining a float by using `$var = 0.0` is correct. While casting is not technically incorrect I don't believe it's something you should use when you don't need to.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `number_format`.

For example:

```
$number = 20;
echo number_format($number,2) // will output 20.00
// number_format($number,$decimals,$dec_point,$thousands_sep)
```

Comment: yes, i know. But i think that this is only for frontend show. In backend functinality will be converted as float... And always the float logic will remove decimals if the decimals are null.